# How do you flip columns in a worksheet in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Given a spreadsheet with 50000+ rows of data there is a subtotal cell on the bottom of each section like so:

```
col1     col2     col3     col4
_______________________________
val      anoth    yetan    more
val      anoth    yetan    more
val      anoth    yetan    more
     subtotal 5   id = red
val      anoth    yetan    more
val      anoth    yetan    more
val      anoth    yetan    more
     subtotal 5   id = green
```

Reading the file in we would like the subtotal column to be on top of the sections of rows so how would you take the entire worksheet and flip it?

Comment: For clarification, by "subtotal column" do you mean "subtotal cell"? It doesnt look like an entire column from what you've shown.

Comment: Do you need to flip the whole table? Cant you just set the cell above the column to equal the subtotal?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand your question you should be able to place your subtotal cell at the top with something like `SUBTOTAL(2,A2:A500)`

Comment: Documentation on the SUBTOTAL function: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/subtotal-function-HP010062463.aspx

Comment: It works sure, but given a large spreadsheet with 50000+ rows and 200+ sections this is an inefficient solution.  the subtotal is not as important to us as the id value (red,green etc).  We need to have these on top of the rows (parsing the file).

Answer (score 0):

This macro did the trick for us.  We had to reverse each column via macro individually but it took way less time than manually flipping everything.

http://www.teachmsoffice.com/excel-macros/reverse-row-column-order-in-excel,52